# Are there any Advanced Classes in the game?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

In regular Fire Emblem games, there are Advanced Classes which are more powerful versions of a previous class. For example a [Mercenary](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Mercenary) who uses swords can become a [Hero](http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Hero) which uses swords and axes. These advanced classes are only obtainable by powering up your character once they have reached level 10+.

Are there any advanced classes in Fire Emblem Heroes?
Or any characters/classes that can use two colours of weapons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no advanced classes in the game. Seeing as the game just came out, though, this answer could get outdated soon.